# Multiple Kafka Listeners With Same GroupId All Receiving Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener configured in our Spring Boot application as follows:

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(topic = 'data.all', partitions = { "0", "1", "2" }), groupId = "kms")
public void listen(ObjectNode message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    // Code to convert to json string and write to ElasticSearch
}
```

This application gets deployed to and run on 3 servers and, despite all having the group id of `kms`, they all get a copy of the message which means I get 3 identical records in Elastic. When I'm running an instance locally, 4 copies get written.

I've confirmed that the producer is only writing 1 message to the topic by checking the count of all messages on the topic before and after the write occurs; it only increases by 1. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you manually assign partitions like that, you are responsible for distributing the partitions across the instances.

The group is ignored for the purpose of partition distribution, but is still used to track offsets, if needed.

You must use group management and let Kafka do the partition assignment for you, or assign the partitions manually for each instance.

Instead of `topicPartitions`, use `topics = "data.all"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try tomorrow but I think when I didn't assign then I had other issues with message duplication even in the same instance. Will let you know!

Comment: So it's slightly better... I'm still getting between 2 and 3 copies (rather than 4) picked up when I have 4 instances running. Still not what should be happening though.

Comment: Never mind, I think someone has an un-updated instance running because when I stopped all 3 servers I still got a copy of the message delivered. I think this solves it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you don't assign partition manually

### Producer Side

- When producer sends a message without any strategy or specifying to which partition message should go then kafka tries to use round robin technic and splits all messages among all available partition.

  - Message in 2 partitions are unique because maximum of only 1 consumer is recommended to listen to a particular partition of a topic.

### Consumer Side

- For example there are 2 partitions of a topic
- Then a consumer(let say `A`) joins with consumer group (lets say `consumer`)
- Partition reassignment happens whenever new consumer joins and 2 partitions get assigned to `A` as we have only one consumer group `consumer`
- Now, consumer `B` tries to join same consumer group `consumer` then again partition reassignment will happen and both A & B will get partition to listen to messages
- As we have only 2 partitions, even if we add more consumers to same consumer group, there will be only 2 consumer who will be listening to the messages sent to the topic because at a time only 2 consumers can get 1-1 partition. To maintain exclusivity of the message consumed at consumer.

What is happening in your case is, more than 1 consumer is listening to same partitions so all the consumers who are listening to same partitions within same consumer group also, will receive messages from that partition. So mutual exclusivity between consumers in a consumer group is lost due to more than 1 consumer is listening same partitions.