# Spring kafkaListener Consumer GroupID for a Partition

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently, We create multiple kafka consumers for a given topic and all the messages in the topic are together processed by all the consumers in the same consumer group.

We want to enhance this now. Instead of creating multiple kaka consumers/listeners reading from the same topic, we want multiple consumers in the same consumer group to read from a specified partition of the topic.

Is it possible? Do we have any reference where we can specify both the consumer group id and partition together in each of our kafka listeners?

Comment: What is the use-case here? Generally, assigning partitions doesn't "enhance" a consumer, and you cannot have multiple consumers in the same group reading the same partition, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you have to use manual partition assignment. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#manual-assignment

> You can also configure POJO listeners with explicit topics and partitions (and, optionally, their initial offsets). The following example shows how to do so:

```java
@KafkaListener(groupId = "thing2", topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0", "1" }),
          @TopicPartition(topic = "topic2", partitions = { "0", "1" })
        })
```

```java
@KafkaListener(groupId = "thing2", topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "2", "3" }),
          @TopicPartition(topic = "topic2", partitions = { "2", "3" })
        })
```

etc.

Comment: Does `groupId` matter? If using the assign API, then "consumer group coordination will be disabled" (from Javadoc)

Comment: You still need a `group.id` if you want to commit offsets - even if group management is not being used; otherwise an exception will be thrown when committing the offset(s). You don't need one if you don't commit offsets and always start from the beginning (or maintain the offsets externally, and perform seeks during startup).

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell.

Comment: Can we have multiple kafka listeners to process the messages from one partition and one message should only be processed by one listener?

I tried below but I see the same message is being processed by multiple listeners. 

@KafkaListener(id="listener1", groupId = "thing2", topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0" }) })

@KafkaListener(id="listener2", groupId = "thing2", topicPartitions = { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0" }) })

Comment: No; each partition can have only one active listener. If you have multiple listeners on a single topic, even if they are in the same group, they will get all the records - offset storage will also be compromised; if one listener is at record 10 and the other is at record 20 and the first one goes down, it will skip 11-20.

Comment: @Gary Wouldn't this a contradict to your following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551368/multiple-kafka-listeners-with-same-groupid-all-receiving-message/56552126#56552126

Comment: if we use topicPartition we can't use groupId .I also have a similar kind of requirement of manual configuration of partition.If I do so I am getting commit failed exception.Here is the link for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421391/facing-caused-by-org-apache-kafka-clients-consumer-commitfailedexception please shed some light .I am totally blocked

Comment: That answer was a bit misleading. Corrected.