# Facing Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.
    This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing.
    You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:155) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1791) [spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1298) [spring-kafka-2.8.6.jar:2.8.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_321]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the part
```

Here is the producer and consumer properties.

**Consumer Properties**

> ```
> #set the server port
> server.port=8004
> #Kafka properties
> spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kakfa server instance
> spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL  
> spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
> spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule\
>   \ required username="****" password="****" ;
> spring.kafka.producer.properties.enable.idempotence=false
> spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
> spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
> spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
> ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location=C://Users//Public//Projects//kafka.jks
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password=****
> request.topic=req_topic
> consumer.group.id=consumer_group_id
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
> ```

**Producer Properties**

> ```
> #set the server port
> server.port=8003
> #Kafka broker properties
> spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kakfa server instance
> spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL  
> spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
> spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule\
>   \ required username="****" password="****" ;
> spring.kafka.producer.properties.enable.idempotence=false
> ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location=C://Users//Public//Projects//kafka.jks
> spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password=****
> #Kafka serializers and deserializers
> spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
> spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
> spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
> #Kafka topic and group configurations
> request.topic=req_topic
> response.topic=resp_topic
> consumer.group.id=consumer_group_id
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
> ```

Tried with following properties but still facing the same issue

> ```
> #Kafka consumer properties
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[request.timeout.ms]=300000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[heartbeat.interval.ms]=1000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[max.poll.interval.ms]=900000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[session.timeout.ms]=600000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[max.poll.records]=100
> ```

Here is my consumer class

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${request.topic}", groupId = "${consumer.group.id}", topicPartitions = {
        @TopicPartition(topic = "${request.topic}", partitions = "${partition}") })
    @SendTo
    public String consumer (String message)
    {
       
        return message;
    }
```

Here is my producer class

> ```
> @Service public class ProducerService {
> @Autowired
> private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingKafkaTemplate;
> @Value("${request.topic}")
> String requestTopic;
> public Object getResponse (Message message)
> {
>     try {
>
>         ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(requestTopic, message);
>         RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> replyFuture =
>             replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
>         ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
>         return consumerRecord.value();
>     }
>     catch (ExecutionException e) {
>         return ResponseEntity
>             .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
>             .body(e.getMessage());
>     }
>     catch (InterruptedException e) {
>         return ResponseEntity
>             .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
>             .body(e.getMessage());
>     }
>     catch (TimeoutException e) {
>         return ResponseEntity
>             .status(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
>             .body(e.getMessage());
>     }
>     catch (Exception e) {
>         return ResponseEntity
>             .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
>             .body("Un expected error occured please try again later. ");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> application properties
>
> ```
> spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
> #spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
> spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
> spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
> #spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
> #spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
> #spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
> #spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
> #spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=5000000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[request.timeout.ms]=300000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[heartbeat.interval.ms]=1000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[max.poll.interval.ms]=900000
> #spring.kafka.consumer.properties[session.timeout.ms]=600000
> #Default properties.
> #request.timeout.ms=30000
> #heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
> #max.poll.interval.ms=300000
> #max.poll.records=500
> #session.timeout.ms=45000
> #Updated properties.
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.request.timeout.ms=300000
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.heartbeat.interval.ms=1000
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=600000
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=100
> spring.kafka.consumer.properties.session.timeout.ms=600000
> spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
> spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
> spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear.

Your listener is taking too long to process the records returned by the poll.

Comment: My requirement is I have a single topic with one group id and  different apps consumes the same topic under the same group . I would like to configure each app with different partition nos like app 1 would consume from  0 to 1 and app 2 would consume from 2 to 3 etc .I tried adding the rebalance listener and configured the max record to 100 and max poll seconds to 600000 but no luck .Still I am getting the same error .If I allow Kafka to do partitioning(i.e remove @TopicParition) I don't see this issue .But if I configure manually then only I could see.

Comment: Also is it a best design to have 1 topic and 1 group with multi partitioning for large scale applications.Basically producer record I am planning to add the partition so that producing and consuming would be from same partition .

Comment: Attaching the application properties also for your reference.

Comment: Manually assigning partitions, instead of using group management, should make no difference when committing offsets. Perhaps you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior so someone can take a look.